# set default on webpage

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have an issue with url direction here. I have used mod_rewrite in apache to rewrite the url from domain.com/page.php to domain.com/path/page.php.

I have some link in the webpage for example `href="newpage.php"` will automatically go to domain.com/path/newpage.php instead of domain.com/newpage.php. May I know is there any php method to set all the default url in the php file itself to avoid this path issue? without using any variable like `href="<?php echo $_SERVER['domain']; ?>newpage.php"`

Comment: Relative URLs are resolved by the client, not by the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how many folders deep the file is you could just backtrack by doing ../newpage.php. So if you're at domain.com/folder/currentpage.php you could do ../newpage.php. To get to domain.com/newpage.php.